# Optimize the SQL Statement with MAX() and VALUES()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

In the following case the target is to return the max value rating of a share:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sd.ShareId
  , CASE 
      WHEN sd.GV01 IS NOT NULL OR sd.GV02 IS NOT NULL OR sd.GV03 IS NOT NULL THEN (
         SELECT MAX(val)
         FROM (VALUES (rmatMG.RankingId), (rmatSG.RankingId), (rmatFG.RankingId)) AS value(val)
         WHERE val IS NOT NULL
    ) 
  END AS minRating
  , sd.TradeValue
FROM dbo.MasterData sd
LEFT JOIN dbo.CfgRatingMatching rmMG ON sd.GV01 = rmMG.RatingIdOne 
LEFT JOIN dbo.CfgRatingmatrix rmatMG ON rmMG.RatingIdCollMatrix = rmatMG.RankingId
LEFT JOIN dbo.CfgRatingMatching rmSG ON sd.GV02 = rmSG.RatingIdTwo 
LEFT JOIN dbo.CfgRatingmatrix rmatSG ON rmSG.RatingIdCollMatrix = rmatSG.RankingId
LEFT JOIN dbo.CfgRatingMatching rmFG ON sd.GV03 = rmFG.RatingIdThree 
LEFT JOIN dbo.CfgRatingmatrix rmatFG ON rmFG.RatingIdCollMatrix = rmatFG.RankingId
```

Do anyone have an idea how to optimize the code? I have a lot of data and the return of the list takes almost more than a minute. It takes too long.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what your data looks like, but your `join`s may be expanding the data to an unmanageable size.

Comment: What indexes do you already have on the tables? What does the plan look like?

Comment: Are all the self joins necessary? Instead you could conditionally join them

Comment: Post your actual execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. How many rows in in the `MasterData` table? Performance will largely be proportional to the number of rows in that table since you have no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It may very well be that you are suffering from a poor database design. There are three rating IDs, which you all treat equally. Why then three different columns? Another table design where you have one ID per row may be preferable. But I don't know enough about your tables to be sure. Also the use of `DISTINCT` in your query looks strange. Are you somehow producing an undesired intermediate result you must get rid of again? It does look like you really want mere aggregation. But again, that's only my impression from what you are showing.

Comment: I think @ThorstenKettner has the right idea here.  Looks like you have a `ShareId` with three columns `GV01, GV02, GV03` and columns meant to match in `CfgRatingMatching`.  The database design just seems like it could be optimized to reduce the number of self joins.

Comment: Why you do not add the requested information? I would like to see your question to be answered.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my Thread later with the additional information :)